# Linear Gradient Background with white text

Tags: html, css

So I have the Title in my Navbar. The text has a linear gradient

```
nav li h1 {
background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,red,#ffae00);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; }
```

and I want the title to turn white and the background stay linear gradient

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/qx96ku4h/

Comment: where is `a` in html?

Comment: don't mind that, it aint a link. It's pretty much a JSS button to scroll back up to the page top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the values back to `initial` to disable the gradient on text and set the color of the text.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  background: #23262b;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

header:after {
  content: "";
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, red, #ffae00);
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -9px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 20px;
}

nav li {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


nav li h1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, #ffae00);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

#myBtn:hover h1 {
  -webkit-background-clip: initial;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">
        <h1>Make text White</h1>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Temani would you know how I can make the background of the Title abit biggoer and thicker? Cuz the text is almost out of the background.

Comment: @AdrianB. i also added some padding for this

Comment: yep sorry lol missed that padding out. Thank you again man :D